# In the opening credits to Deep Space Nine what are those flashing things on the outside of the station?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

At the 1:18-1:20 mark of the following opening credits video for DS9 there are some flashing objects that I've never seen in an episode.

I don't really recall them ever going outside the station and doing repairs externally. It looks like this might be an automatic welding apparatus of some sort.

Does anybody have any idea what those two flashing objects are? If they are some kind of automated welders, if you have any info on them, their functionality, etc. that'd be great.

If there's a DS9 companion or manual of some sort that his this info, please cite what it's called. EU and writers notes, are welcome.

If there's a DS9 episode where they go outside the station to effect repairs please mention the episode.

Comment: I think they are welders. They added them after they saw the cool Babylon 5 Intro with welders working at the station. :-)

Comment: @Hothie LOL. Didn't Babylon 5 come out after this? Man I'm getting old.

Comment: They both started in 1993. DS9 changed its intro in one of the later seasons. Even the music was pimped and sounds to me like the style of the music of the original B5 pilot intro. :-)

Comment: _"If there's a DS9 episode where they go outside the station to affect repairs please mention the episode."_ They would have to have done after "To The Death", no? An entire docking pylon was completely severed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The flashing you see is actually from two men in yellow EV suits using some kind of welding equipment (presumably to repair the station and to add additional weaponry). You can also see a third man coming in from the left with a metal panel. Later in the same sequence, you also see a [Cargo Management Unit](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cargo_management_unit)

Quoting from the DS9 Companion:

> **ILM's John Knoll, responsible for the solar ships the appeared in
>   "Explorers" and "Accession." contributed the little worker bees and
>   the tiny welders toiling on the pylons.** '*I made about half a dozen
>   little bits and pieces for the sequence."* says Knoll, including, he
>   notes with a smile, '*a generic alien ship with blue glowy engines.*"
>
> "*Make it bigger, make it stronger.* *that's what we talked about.*"
>   McCarthy says. "*We weren't lonely anymore, and the **new visuals showed
>   a lot of activity. They were welding and doing stuff and there were a
>   lot of ships running around.** One French horn no longer made a lot of
>   sense, so I put all six French horns in. I also added a counterpoint
>   to the bottom end. Just put more movement into it in total, and I did
>   some power-chording in all those new downbeats.*"

Comment: I don't know how you find this stuff so fast but it's awesome. I was wondering from the quote, is he referring to just those two episodes or the opening credits. How do you link the quote to it being two men in yellow EV suits? +1

Comment: @JMFB - The flashing is clearly welding. Ergo, these are welders. Also, you can see their little legs waggling in the HD version.

Comment: Good work Richard; I've seen work bees do welding before but the scale probably isn't right!

Comment: @Valorum The HD version? When did they do a remaster of the DSN opening?

Comment: It's amazing how you know they're men!

Answer (score 10):

Not 100% sure, but I reckon they're some form of [Work bee](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Work_bee).

Here's a screenshot of the scene you're referring to:

[image: Scene]

A Work bee is a tiny little craft used for maintenance work (seen in the beginning of *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* working on the *Enterprise*): I've included an image below:

[image: Work bee]

The 'flashing' you describe is probably maintenance work.  I'm not 100% sure on the scale, but considering their size against DS9 and that these are single-pilot craft, it is entirely plausible it is a Work bee, perhaps even an automated one.

Work bees have been seen in DS9 before (apologies for the poor picture) in *The Muse*; *For the Uniform*, *A Simple Investigation* and *Hard Time*:

[image: Work bee outside DS9]

Comment: +1 Good answer. Let me see if somebody comes up with something else. Otherwise I'll award it a correct answer.

Comment: @JMFB thanks!  Let *me* know if anyone comes up with something different; I'd be really interested to see if they do :)

Comment: Yes this is quite clearly welding/repairs.

Comment: An interesting answer, unfortunately not correct./

Comment: @N_Soong Richard did it again. Check out his post... We need to hack into Richards computer and get all his resource info, lol.

Comment: @Richard your quote indicates it's atleast both worker bees and maybe human welders

Comment: @cde - The worker bees are seen much earlier in the sequence.

Comment: @N_Soong : This is great.  I'm impressed with how much you got correct from speculation alone. :-)

Answer (score -2):

I believe it’s clear that the objects are intended to represent humans in red environmental suits performing a repair on the docking arm.  The problem is this is seriously (grossly!) out of scale.  There is another subsequent scene showing the Defiant departing, and again the scale is way way off.  I don’t understand why this was allowed, as someone must have noticed this before.  I suppose they expected the sins to be hidden on the small screen.  Oh well.

Comment: While it may be clear to you, it is not to OP. Can you provide any reasoning as to why the flashing things are humans in red environmental suits?

Comment: It doesn't seem that out of scale. That pylon is in the extreme foreground of the shot, and the rest of the station is quite far in the background. Seems believable scale to me.